# Read/write files on server from Android

Tags: android, web-services, file

I'm working on a small project for fun, which involves Android and a web server.

I want some suggestion on the protocol/model to use that is best suited for the following scenario.

**Server side**

I have setup the following 5 components:

- A config file `rule.csv` which contains 6 columns and about 20 rows. Each row in that file a rule.
- A "switch" file `RUN.on` or `RUN.off`
- A Java program that runs according to those rules, if `RUN.on` exists
- A cronjob that runs the Java program every 5min.
- A PHP page. `control.php?run=on` will rename `RUN.off` to `RUN.on`
  `control.php?run=off` will set `RUN.off`

**On Android**

- An app that submits to `control.php` to change the running status.

**Goal**

Now I want to add a feature to that android app, such that I can view and add/remove the rule in `rule.csv`. That requires a **Android <--> Server <--> File** communication. However, getting the whole file using PHP, and transfer it back after editing does not seem to be a good way in this case.

Since this is a project just for fun, getting it to work is not my priority; I'd like to look for a good model that handles this kind of task and I'm willing to learn other languages if necessary. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the rule file is kinda big or you would just transfer it.

Adding a new rule seems pretty simple - enter the data on the Android and send the rule to the server.  But how do you want the Android user to pick the rule to remove?  Can you just transfer the names of all of the rules, let the user choose the rule, and then just send the rule name back?